# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes when it copies from a external disk large data

Tags: usb, gnome-shell, external-hdd, 20.04

I don't know what other information I can give you, but I know that this problem has been on Ubuntu for a long time (the Linux Mint that I have is based in the 16.04 environment). I hope that someone can solve this. If you need more information or tests in my computer I will be happy to help you.

More potentially useful data:

- The external Hard Disk is a Toshiba with 3.0 USB.
- My computer has a 3.0 Port and the average speed was 80.0 MB/s (it was quite good I think).
- The output with the `sysctl vm.swappiness`: `vm.swappiness = 60`
- The output of the `free -h` command:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           11Gi       3,3Gi       179Mi       598Mi       8,2Gi       7,5Gi
Swap:         3,9Gi        65Mi       3,8Gi
```

- My computer has two slots of RAM. My computer initially has just 4GB DDR3 but I bought another 8GB later. That's why my systems works now with 11.6GB according to the data that Ubuntu gives me.
- The output of the `inxi -Fxz` command:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X455LAB v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X455LAB v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: X455LAB.208 date: 08/03/2015 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 8.0 Wh condition: 21.4/37.3 Wh (57%) 
  model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery status: Charging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-5500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 19156 
  Speed: 799 MHz min/max: 500/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 799 2: 798 
  3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-26-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel port: e000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Lite-On driver: ath9k v: kernel port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: vmnet1 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-2: vmnet8 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.82 TiB used: 588.81 GiB (31.6%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB 
  temp: 37 C 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01UBD100 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 274.01 GiB used: 38.01 GiB (13.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
  ID-2: swap-1 size: 3.91 GiB used: 70.4 MiB (1.8%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0 C mobo: 27.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 2600 
Info:
  Processes: 306 Uptime: 20h 16m Memory: 11.61 GiB used: 3.13 GiB (27.0%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Does your external HDD have its own AC power supply?

Comment: @heynnema thanks for your help, I have already edited with the command that you suggests. For your question: No, the power supply is the 3.0 USB port.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I am making the `disk` test that you have told me, the process is taking time and I can't do it at any time. When the process finish I am going to upload both screenshots. The BIOS and the RAM Test takes more time than I expected, this is my work computer, I could just do it at weekends. Thanks for your help

Comment: What was the final solution for the problem?

Comment: Hi @heynnema I think it was the update of the BIOS. I made the test of the disk and it didn't show anything wrong in the disk and the RAM process finalized without problem. After the BIOS update and RAM check the Hard Disk works better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUSTeK product: X455LAB v: 1.0

You have a very old BIOS, v: X455LAB.208 date: 08/03/2015.

The latest version is 302 from 6/4/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X455LA/HelpDesk_BIOS/). Make sure to select X455LAB as your model #.

**Note**: Perform good data backups before upgrading the BIOS.

**Note**: Upgrading the BIOS may, or may not, solve your external disk copy problem.

**Disk**

You didn't state how large your external USB 3.0 disk is, but if it's 1TB or larger, you'll need to connect the AC power adapter to the external case, or use a powered USB hub. The USB 3.0 port normally doesn't have enough power to support external devices with high power needs.

**SMART**

Start the `Disks` application, select the desired HDD (check both internal and external disks), go to the "hamburger" icon, and select SMART Data & Tests. View the SMART Data window. Edit your question, and add the screenshot(s) if you wish me to review them for you.

**memtest**

Since you recently added RAM, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.